# Deploy Sinatra app on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have simple Sinatra app.

**web.rb:**

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do 
    "Hello" 
end
```

**Gemfile:***

```
source :rubygems

gem 'sinatra', '1.1.0'
gem 'thin', '1.2.7'
```

**config.ru:**

```
require './web'
run Sinatra::Application
```

But when I deploy my app on Heroku I'll get the error on logs:

```
2012-03-27T19:17:48+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H14 (No web processes running) -> GET furious-waterfall-6586.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Anything else useful from `heroku logs`?

Comment: Nothing. Only this error. 'heroku ps' shows that there is not running processes. 'heroku restart' didn't help me

Comment: May we know what the problem was?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just got sinatra-bootstrap as template for my project and it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need a `Procfile` file alongside your `config.ru` to tell Heroku how to run your app. Here is the content of an example `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec ruby web.rb -p $PORT
```

[Heroku Ruby docs on Procfiles](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

EDIT: Here's a sample `config.ru` from one of my sinatra/Heroku apps:

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path("../", __FILE__)
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require './web'
run Sinatra::Application
```

You may need to require sinatra and rubygems for it to work.

Comment: @demas I've added a sample config.ru file in case that helps. Your Gemfile looks solid (though that is a kinda old version of sinatra, not sure if that plays in at all)

Comment: Can you pls create minimal Sinatra-app on Github? I have tried your changes, but it doesn't help me

Comment: Sure, I'll spin one up in a few hours if you don't get it figured by then. Sorry, my sinatra apps thus far have been closed source :((

Comment: You might find this sinatra-bootstrap project useful in the meantime: https://github.com/adambair/sinatra-bootstrap

Comment: as far as i know a Procfile should not be needed.

Comment: You do not need the Procfile, unless you wish to run a webserver other than Webrick.  Check out `heroku ps` and you can see what command was executed by Heroku to run your app!

Answer (score 25):

Here's how to create a minimal sinatra app that deploys to heroku:

app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "hello world"
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'heroku'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
```

config.ru:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Type these commands in your command line to deploy (without the `$` signs):

```
$ bundle install
$ git init
$ git add -f app.rb Gemfile Gemfile.lock config.ru
$ git commit -am "initial commit"
$ heroku create <my-app-name>
$ git push heroku master
```

Then test your app:

```
$ curl <my-app-name>.heroku.com
```

and you should see:

```
hello world
```

Comment: I got this error when trying the above "The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not."

Comment: @JGallardo, thanks for your comment! Bundler wants you to use HTTPS instead of HTTP, so you just have to change the line `source :rubygems` to `source 'https://rubygems.org'`. I changed that in my answer as well. Cheers

Comment: The `heroku` gem is now deprecated (replaced by the Heroku Toolbelt). More info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby

Answer (score 10):

I have had this problem a number of times in the past, and it was all because I didn't include my config.ru file with the requiring of [app].rb & then pushing to Heroku. Even if I added it afterwards and restarted, Heroku would never pick it up.

- Destroy your small app on Heroku's site (http://www.heroku.com)
- Then remove the remote from your project folder

  ```
  $ git remote rm heroku
  ```
- Then recreate the app

Comment: I just had the same problem reported by the OP, this is the only thing that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Same thing here. It seems that once you pushed an app with a missing or incorrect config.ru, the only fix is to recreate it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 1):

As an update, here is a *slightly* more minimal app that I created, and confirmed to be working as of today. The thin gem was not needed, and a Procfile was not needed to get an initial working app.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
```

**config.ru**

```
require './app'

run Sinatra::Application
```

Note: The require line uses './app' instead of 'app'.

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello, World! Find me in app.rb'
end
```

If you want to use this template, you can copy it, bundle, and push the Git repo.

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial sinatra app"
$ bundle
$ git add Gemfile.lock
$ git commit -m "bundle install"
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku open
```

Comment: Gemfile did it for me

Answer (score 0):

By adding the gem 'heroku' to the Gemfile, I got it working. No Procfile needed.