# Application Error when deploying a simple rack application on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rack, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-san

i am trying to deploy my app on heroku 
it contains 5 files
1.config.ru
with code

```
require 'rack'
require './myapp'

run MyApp.new
```

2.Gemfile
with code

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem 'grape'
gem 'sequel'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'rake'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rack'
group :test do
  gem "rspec", "~> 2.12.0"
  gem "rack-test", "~> 0.6.2"
  gem "rspec-core", "~> 2.12.2"
  gem "rspec-expectations", "~> 2.12.1"
  gem "rspec-mocks", "~> 2.12.1"
  gem "capybara", "~> 2.0.2"
  gem "nokogiri", "~> 1.5.6"
end
```

3.Gemfile.lock which is created automatically
4.myapp.rb with code

```
# my_app.rb
class MyApp
  def call env
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Hello Rack Participants"]] 
  end
end
```

5.Procfile with code

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru
```

then i call bundle install

after that rackup config.ru
its working perfectly fine as expected
but after that i try to deploy it on heroku and getting application error
i executed following commands for this

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

a web browser open with application error
when i run command heroku logs 
then its giving me logs

```
2013-02-04T05:34:17+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=quiet-caverns-8170.herokuapp.com fwd=121.245.34.235 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

can any one please help why i am getting this error on heroku and hopw to rectify it??

here is full logs for heroku

```
2013-02-04T05:30:44+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:30:44+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN resource by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:30:44+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:30:45+00:00 heroku[api]: Add DATABASE_URL config by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:30:45+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:30:45+00:00 heroku[api]: Add  config by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:30:45+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:30:45+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:30:45+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 243e86c by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:30:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby web.rb`
2013-02-04T05:30:52+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bundle: command not found
2013-02-04T05:30:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-02-04T05:30:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby web.rb`
2013-02-04T05:30:58+00:00 app[web.1]: ruby: No such file or directory -- web.rb (LoadError)
2013-02-04T05:31:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-02-04T05:31:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-04T05:31:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-02-04T05:31:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby web.rb`
2013-02-04T05:31:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-04T05:31:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=quiet-caverns-8170.herokuapp.com fwd=121.245.34.235 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-02-04T05:31:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=quiet-caverns-8170.herokuapp.com fwd=121.245.34.235 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-02-04T05:31:18+00:00 app[web.1]: ruby: No such file or directory -- web.rb (LoadError)
2013-02-04T05:31:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-02-04T05:33:42+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-02-04T05:33:52+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:33:52+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy eb490fb by ritesh@iritesh.com
2013-02-04T05:33:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-02-04T05:33:53+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-02-04T05:33:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-04T05:34:17+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=quiet-caverns-8170.herokuapp.com fwd=121.245.34.235 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-02-04T05:33:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru`
2013-02-04T05:33:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-02-04T05:33:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 05:33:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=9292
2013-02-04T05:33:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 9292, should be 16705 (see environment variable PORT)
2013-02-04T05:33:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 05:33:57] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-02-04T05:33:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 05:33:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-02-04T05:33:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-02-04T05:41:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru`
2013-02-04T05:41:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-02-04T05:41:24+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 05:41:24] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-02-04T05:41:24+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 05:41:24] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-02-04T05:41:24+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 05:41:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=9292
2013-02-04T05:41:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-02-04T05:41:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 9292, should be 46347 (see environment variable PORT)
2013-02-04T05:41:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-02-04T05:41:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-04T05:51:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 9292, should be 15335 (see environment variable PORT)
2013-02-04T05:51:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru`
2013-02-04T05:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 05:51:59] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-02-04T05:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 05:51:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-02-04T05:51:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-02-04T05:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 05:51:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=9292
2013-02-04T05:52:01+00:00 hero
ku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-02-04T05:55:18+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=quiet-caverns-8170.herokuapp.com fwd=121.245.34.235 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-02-04T05:55:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=quiet-caverns-8170.herokuapp.com fwd=121.245.34.235 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-02-04T06:01:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-02-04T06:02:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-04T06:12:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-02-04T06:12:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru`
2013-02-04T06:12:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-02-04T06:12:17+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 06:12:17] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-02-04T06:12:17+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 06:12:17] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-02-04T06:12:17+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-04 06:12:17] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=9292
2013-02-04T06:12:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 9292, should be 35684 (see environment variable PORT)
2013-02-04T06:12:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-04T06:12:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Comment: I would look at the lines before and after the line you posted, sometimes there is more information. I have had similar problems when I had to perform db:migrate but for to.

Comment: no you can see there is no db migration its a simple rake app wait posting full logs

Comment: now please help why i am getting this error

Comment: It says "bundle: command not found", if it was a rails app heroku knows that and installs bundler before running bundle install and the starting rails; have you tried it without the procfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not specifying the correct port for the app to run on. Try switching your Procfile to the following

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV
```

See [Deploy Sinatra app on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896216/deploy-sinatra-app-on-heroku) and [Deploying sinatra app (with config.ru) on heroku cedar stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340943/deploying-sinatra-app-with-config-ru-on-heroku-cedar-stack) for similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not binding to the port in `$PORT`, so we kill your process. You must change your `Procfile` to include `-p $PORT`.